# Storing data as cache in oracle database for certain time

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have **oracle query that takes 10 to 20 min** but I want user to see those data immediately. The data is stored for **certain time and data is live** and each hour new data is added. Is it possible to cache these data so that the query would take less time or no time?

```
Note:I am using linked server
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is one of the neat new features of 11g. Oracle build in the RESULT_CACHE_MODE. This mode allows us to be able to cache result sets of queries.

There are three methods of initializing this. 
1. Set as sys variable (alter system)
2. current session variable (alter session)
3. use a hint in your specific query

Default this parameter is set to MANUAL. you can check by executing this query in your SQL session.

```
SQL> SELECT value FROM v$parameter WHERE name = 'result_cache_mode';
```

My personal preference is to keep the default value MANUAL and hint the query which I want to cache as I only have a couple of them which I want cached. This way I can select wich query is cached and none will be cached by default.

To cache a specific query you will need to set the /*+ RESULT_CACHE */ hint in your query. Here's an example.

```
SELECT /*+ RESULT_CACHE */ foo,
       bar,
       lorem
FROM   dual
WHERE  foo > 10;
```

Hope this helps you!

EDIT:

You should also check these system variables to see if the size is acceptable and you can also see and set the expiration time in system variable result_cache_remote_expiration

```
SELECT name, value, isdefault
FROM   v$parameter
WHERE  name LIKE 'result_cache%';
```